# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$(".cb-enable").click(function(){
    $("#repetitive").show();
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.cb-disable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', true);
    $("#repetitiveHidden").empty();
    $("#repetitiveHidden").val("true");
});
$(".cb-disable").click(function(){
    $("#repetitive").hide();
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.cb-enable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', false);
    $("#repetitiveHidden").empty();
    $("#repetitiveHidden").val("false");
});
$(".overnight-enable").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.overnight-disable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', true);
    $("#overnightHidden").empty();
    $("#overnightHidden").val("true");
});
$(".overnight-disable").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.overnight-enable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', false);
    $("#overnightHidden").empty();
    $("#overnightHidden").val("false");
});
$(".rep-daily").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.rep-weekly',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', true);
    $("#reccurType").empty();
    $("#reccurType").val("true");
});
$(".rep-weekly").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.rep-daily',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', false);
    $("#reccurType").empty();
    $("#reccurType").val("false");
});
$(".rep-cycle").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.rep-endDate',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', true);
    $("#reccurWay").empty();
    $("#reccurWay").val("true");
    $("#endDate").hide();
    $("#cycle").show();
});
$(".rep-endDate").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.rep-cycle',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', false);
    $("#reccurWay").empty();
    $("#reccurWay").val("false");
    $("#cycle").hide();
    $("#endDate").show();
});

 })(jQuery);
```

At this line:

```
})(jQuery);
```

I have the error Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
Please help

Comment: Probably the best-ever excuse for needing a fast answer on SO.

Comment: @GalV he says the line in his question.

Comment: all code is in one line, try commenting/removing parts of your code to check where the error is...

Answer (score 3):

Just remove this:

```
 })(jQuery);
```

to

```
 });
```

Because it's not an anonymous function you're calling, but the document ready, which does not need such direct call.